# Add a user to all channels including private channels in all Teams in Microsoft Teams

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I need to add a user to all channels in all teams in Microsoft Teams.

I tried this:

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams
$AllTeams = Get-Team

Foreach ($Team in $AllTeams)
{Add-TeamUser -GroupId $Team.GroupID -User USERS-EMAIL -Role Owner
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2}
```

And it adds them to the team but not all the channels, namely private channels.

Answer (score 1):

Private channel membership is separate from Team membership; that's kind of the point of them being private; you don't want someone in a Team to have access to private channels within that Team automatically (even the owner of a Team doesn't automatically have access to any private channels, unless they create them or added to them). To add a user to a private channel requires the `Add-TeamChannelUser` command from the `MicrosoftTeamsPowerShell` module.

Use this line to add someone to a private channel of a specified team:

```bash
Add-TeamChannelUser -GroupId $Team.GroupID -User <USERS-EMAIL> -DisplayName <NAME OF CHANNEL> #New line
```

Adding someone to a private channel will complete within the PowerShell environment immediately but may take some time before that user shows up in the Teams client.

Comment: Our purpose is we have certain admins who audit these channels for different reasons. Compliance, QA, etc. We need a way to add these admins to all channels in all teams cause manually adding them takes half a day or more at this point. Our issue is having to display the Channel name. I tried getting the channel GroupID like I did in mine and filling that as a variable but it fails saying it is NULL.

Comment: If you are trying to get the link/ID to private channel, it is not possible. Could you please let us know if you are trying anything else.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT If you are a Microsoft developer working on Teams and the PowerShell module for it, consider this a request to expose that information.

Comment: @TylerH - You can suggest this feature at [Microsoft Teams feedback portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).